# Question about Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, convex-geometry

Let $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $L^{p}(X)$ denotes the Banach space of $p$-integrable functions $f: X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $1<p<\infty$. It is clear that the space $(L^p(X),\|\cdot\|_{p})$ is a strictly convex Banach space for $p > 1$, taking into account that
$$
\|f\|_p = \left(\int_X |f(x) |^p dx
\right)^{1/p}, 
$$
with the Lebesgue measure.

If we consider the space $L^p(X)\oplus_{p}L^p(X)$ with the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\oplus_{p}} : L^p(X)\oplus_p L^p(X)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ defined by
$$
\|(f,g)\|_{\oplus_{p}} = (\|f\|_p^p + \|g\|_p^p)^{1/p}
$$
My question is prove that $(L^p(X)\oplus_{p} L^p(X),\|\cdot\|_{\oplus_p})$ is also strictly convex Banach space.

I hope this result is correct, but the problem is the terms raised to $p$. I am using the characterization that $h,k\in L^p(X)\oplus_{p} L^p(X)$, $h\neq k$  and such that $\|h\|_{\oplus_p} = 1 = \|k\|_{\oplus_p}$, then $\|h+k\|_{\oplus_p} < 1$.

Any idea?

Comment: 1) You may want to pick $X$ Borel (or Lebesgue) measurable and non empty. 2) You may want to specify the norm you put on $L^p$ since the strict convexity depends on the norm. 3) What is $r$? 4) I am not sure that $L^\infty$ is strictly convex. It seems that you are asking $1 < p = r< \infty$ so that's ok. 5) To end your proof check again the characterization of strict convexity.

Comment: You are right. I correct the post.

Comment: Your characterization of strict convexity is still incorrect. And you should still specify that $p < \infty$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk That's right!

Comment: You have not resolved the problem with the characterization of strict convexity. What if $h = k$? Or what if $h$ and $k$ are not quite equal but very close together?

Comment: That's right! What's the correct characterization of strictly convex?

Comment: @diracdeltafunk what is the definition of a strictly convex Banach space?

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez let $(\mathcal{B}, \|\cdot\|) $ be a Banach space. It is said to be a strictly convex Banach space if for all $x, y\in\mathcal{B}$ with $\|x\| =1=\|y\|$ and $x\neq y$ we have that $\|(1-\lambda) x+ \lambda y\| < 1$ for every $0<\lambda <1$.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez that's ok, thank you!! Now, I think that the question is complete. Thank you for your comment

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez this it what I think, but I don't know how to prove it or a reference for that result.

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez thank you very much!!

Comment: @Mariano Suárez-Álvarez I'll do it, of course!!